# RestDataPanacheException: Failed to list the entities when table is empty

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, quarkus, quarkus-panache

When I call an API that finds all entries in a table, and that table is empty, this is the result I expect when using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`:

[image]

But when using `quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache` it throws a 500 error saying

```
Mapping an unhandled RestDataPanacheException: io.quarkus.rest.data.panache.RestDataPanacheException: Failed to list the entities
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page index must be >= 0 : -1
```

Somehow when my table is empty, my page index is -1 instead of 0.

[image]

The exception itself comes from `quarkus-rest-data-panache`. Is this a bug in that package? Or how can I make it return an empty list?

[image]

It seems to be the implementation class of `org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource` calling the pagination from `io.quarkus.panache.common` with a negative index.

[image]

Also I'm pretty sure the issue is with `quarkus-spring-data-rest` as that's where the exception is from.

[image]

Comment: Can you please open an issue on Github?

Comment: Added a bug here: https://github.com/quarkusio/code.quarkus.io/issues/553

Comment: Please open issues on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus. The repo you linked is for `code.quarkus.io`